# Ruby on Rails - params from Paypal : invalid byte sequence in utf-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, encoding, paypal

I'm following [this tutorial to integrate Paypal](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails) to my Rails app but I have a problem with the hook. Paypal returns me the url via POST but I keep having the error :

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
  app/controllers/purchases_controller.rb:24:in `hook'
```

Here is my hook :

```
protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
    def hook
        params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
        status = params[:payment_status]
        if status == "Completed"
          @purchase = Purchase.find params[:invoice]
          Line 24 --> @purchase.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], date: Time.now
        end
        render nothing: true
    end
```

I tried multiple solutions such as `notification_params: params.encoding(xxx)` or `force_encode(xxx)` without success. I cannot use `encode` or whatever because params is an `ActiveRecord::Parameters`, not a `String`...

The problem seems to be that, in Paypal my name is `"Stéphane"` but it returns `"St\xE9phane"`.

Here is the complete log from the server :

```
Started POST "/hook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-26 11:59:51 +0100
Processing by PurchasesController#hook as HTML
  Parameters: {"mc_gross"=>"1.00", "invoice"=>"19", "protection_eligibility"=>"Eligible", "address_status"=>"unconfirmed", "payer_id"=>"FSXBUQDGG6KWN", "tax"=>"0.00", "address_street"=>"Av. de la Pelouse, 87648672 Mayet", "payment_date"=>"03:57:09 Oct 26, 2014 PDT", "payment_status"=>"Completed", "charset"=>"windows-1252", "address_zip"=>"75002", "first_name"=>"St\xE9phane", "mc_fee"=>"0.34", "address_country_code"=>"FR", "address_name"=>"St\xE9phane Xxxxx", "notify_version"=>"3.8", "custom"=>"", "payer_status"=>"verified", "business"=>"stephanexxxxx@gmail.com", "address_country"=>"France", "address_city"=>"Paris", "quantity"=>"1", "verify_sign"=>"AOLXbVgQrAtqa0Lllz6erhuaVkd-ADHLMH5k6uuEypyAZ7WCQUuOpfxY", "payer_email"=>"xxxxxxx@outlook.com", "txn_id"=>"5SD166511T176754U", "payment_type"=>"instant", "last_name"=>"Xxxxx", "address_state"=>"Alsace", "receiver_email"=>"stephanexxxxxxx@gmail.com", "payment_fee"=>"0.34", "receiver_id"=>"ZNER97N82WKY2", "txn_type"=>"web_accept", "item_name"=>"XXXX", "mc_currency"=>"USD", "item_number"=>"1", "residence_country"=>"FR", "test_ipn"=>"1", "handling_amount"=>"0.00", "transaction_subject"=>"", "payment_gross"=>"1.00", "shipping"=>"0.00", "ipn_track_id"=>"d4e0d603abd89"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
  Purchase Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "purchases".* FROM "purchases"  WHERE "purchases"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
  app/controllers/purchases_controller.rb:24:in `hook'
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [rack-utf8_sanitizer](https://github.com/whitequark/rack-utf8_sanitizer/)?

Comment: Yes @papirtiger and i got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more extra deeply searches, I found the right solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504253/1805275

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tries without any success I decided to bypass the issue. Since by database field is a text column, what I did is to create a String of all my parameters. After that, I was able to store my String into my text field database column.

```
protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
def hook
  params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
  status = params[:payment_status]
  if status == "Completed"

    @purchase = Purchase.find params[:invoice]
    parameters = String.new
    params.each do |key, value|
      parameters += key + " = " + value + " | "
    end

    @purchase.update_attributes notification_params: parameters, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], date: Time.now
  end

  render nothing: true
end
```